# Question regarding hook_user_presave() and setting roles

Tags: 7, users

When a new user is created, either via admin or by normal user registration, I need to assign a custom role to that user.  It works fine, but I'm not convinced I've checked the user status enough.

In my hook_user_presave() implementation, I check to make sure the administration role isn't set, and uid isn't 1.  To set my role:

```
if ($account->uid == 1 || array_search('administrator', $account->roles))
        return;

$account->roles[] = 'my_custom_role';
```

I only want to do this if it is a brand new user being created/inserted.  The documentation says hook_user_presave() is called if the user is being updated.  What is the best way to check if this is a brand new user creation?  Would uid be set to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [hook_user_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) says the hook is invoked when an user account is updated, or created, not just when the user account is updated.

If you look at [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7), you will notice that `$account->is_new` is set before invoking `hook_user_presave()`, when the user account is being created. If the account is being updated, `$account->is_new` is not set, and `$account->original` contains the user object before any changes.

In Drupal 8, `$user->is_new` will be replaced with [Entity::isNew()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Entity.php/function/Entity%3a%3aisNew/8).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the $account->is_new flag is how to test.  I've been testing and it seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`hook_user_presave()` is fine, just pay attention to `$account->is_new`.
And save fields in the `$edit` variable in the usual format, ex:

```
if ($account->is_new) {
  $edit['field_time'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = (string)time();
}
```

`$edit` is passed as reference and so you don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try [hook_user_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) which is called only when saving a new user.
Also, make sure that $account->uid is set. If uid is set, that means some save function( user_save() ) is called before.

Also, try in_array() instead of array_search. You just wanted to check if the role is in the array, which in_array does out of the box.

Comment: I looked at hook_user_insert(), but that is called after the insert.  If there was a quick API function I could call to pass a UID and roll id, then that would work as well.

Comment: Yes.. so you have the uid there. Also, make sure that you pass $account by reference (&$account) or your changes won't get saved.

Comment: What is a quick API call to set a role to a user?  I couldn't find one.